# Анонимные функции php

Tags: php

Вообщем есть такая проблема

```
$arr = array(
'some_val',
function(){
  echo "hey!";
}
)
```

Приводит к ошибке (не ожидалось function), подскажите, не смотря на поддержку php анонимных функций и последней версии php на сервере, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Начнем с того, что чего вы хотели добиться этой конструкцией?  
И версия php у вас какая?

Comment: Он хочет как в джаваскрипте )

Comment: Да, он хочет как в js. Хочется, чтобы потом можно было вызывать примерно так: $arr[0]($params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Анонимные функции появились в PHP начиная с версии 5.3.0](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php)**
**[Посмотреть пример использования](http://ideone.com/TpFn3s)**
**[Как создать функцию с переменным количеством переменных](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.func-get-args.php)**

```
class Foo {
    function __construct() {
        $this->test = array(
            'some_val',
            function() {
                $args = func_get_args();
                $username = isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : false;
                return "hey" . (is_string($username) ? ", {$username}!" : "!");
            }
        );
    }
}

$var = new Foo;

echo $var->test[1]() . PHP_EOL;      # hey!
echo $var->test[1]('Arc') . PHP_EOL; # hey, Arc!
```

Comment: @Arc, покажите, как объявляете, как вызываете и т.д.

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/6S7EAy

Comment: @Arc, а так вообще объявлять нельзя свойства класса в php.свойства, как и дефолтные параметры функций можно объявлять только с примитивами, видимо анонимная функция  примитивом не является.

Comment: Что это означает?

Comment: @Arc это значит, что вот тут $b определен неправильно (та же ошибка что у вас) почему 

    function test($a=1,$b=function(){}){};

анонимка не попадает под констаное выражение я не уверен... 

цитата из [доки](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.properties.php).
>Это описание может содержать инициализацию, но инициализация дожна применяться для константных значений - то есть, переменные должны быть вычислены во время компиляции и не должны зависеть от информации программы во время выполнения для их вычисления.

Comment: @Arc так вот не работает, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), насчет "не выполнена" не понимаю, я думаю  просто они не стали заморачиваться с рекурсивной компиляцией

Comment: Не думаю, что компиляция обязательно должна быть рекурсивной

Comment: @Arc, а как иначе проверить, что функция вообще компилируется ?

Comment: @eicto, я думал, что вопрос в том, как скомпилировать а не как проверить